# XCode - Swift - App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, beta

I have been trying to deal with this problem for a while now, and I'm hoping someone has a solution that I haven't yet seen.

I am using XCode 7 and am testing my app on an iPad (ios 9 beta). I have tried adding the code below to every instance of Info.plist and it doesn't work.

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
           <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    </dict>
```

I have tried decreasing the Deployment Target to 8.4. I have tried restarting both my laptop I am developing on and the iPad.

I just don't know what else to do. Thanks.

Comment: Just saying: App Transport Security is there for a reason. I strongly suspect that apps which are just turning it off will fail to be allowed on the app store, unless they have a very good reason why security isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

You may just be adding it in an invalid position, it should be inside the main `<dict>` tag. Try adding as the first element in the first dictionary like [this](https://gist.github.com/mttcrsp/82748862d4d44c1fcfd4).